# Cucumber : Maven : Dcucumber.options : How to have multiple tags with one of them being IGNORE TAG like "NOT @tag"

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-java, mvn-repo

I am trying to run Cucumber Scenarios with Maven using below command:

mvn clean install -Pgeneric-runner -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore '-Dcucumber.options=--tags @tag1 and not @tag2'

The above Maven command is failing. However, when I am removing the "not @tag2" piece from the command, it is executing fine without any failures.

.
Is it possible to fix the above maven command, so that it can execute the scenarios having "@tag1" and exclude any scenario having "@tag2".

Requesting assistance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using?

Comment: Hi , I am using cucumber 2.4.0 ... Kindly assist how do I resolve the issue above.

Comment: One more thing, when I am running from the TestRunner.java class ... It is working fine.  @CucumberOptions(tags = {"@tag1 and not @tag2"})

Answer (score 0):

So you're using a rather old version of Cucumber. And a lot of things about it are rather weird. For example `cucumber.options` accepts command line arguments.

This means that:

```bash
'-Dcucumber.options=--tags @tag1 and not @tag2'
```

is interpreted as the command line option:

```bash
--tags @tag1 and not @tag2
```

Which is then read as:

```bash
--tags <the tag you want to run> <feature file> <feature file> <feature file>
```

So you have to tell Cucumber that the tag expression belongs together:

```bash
--tags "@tag1 and not @tag2"
```

Which you then nest into another command line argument:

```bash
'-Dcucumber.options=--tags "@tag1 and not @tag2"'
```

And that might just work. It depends a little bit on how your shell handles the quotes.

You should probably upgrade. Then you can use `-Dcucumber.filter.tags=tag1 and not @tag2` which does behave normally. You can find the release notes to help you upgrade here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/release-notes